# Shell Script Output not written to file properly

Tags: shell-script, imagemagick, output

I tried to put the output of my program into a text file. It appends the echo commands to the file properly, but the imagemagick "compare" command is not appended to the file. It just STOUD's the "PSNR value", which is returned by compare method into terminal.

Is there a way to append this commands output to the textfile too? Also if I call my script just with "./script.sh > test.txt" it doesn't print anything more than the echos to file and compare results to terminal.

Here's a part of my code:

```
ls images/toconvert/ > lsout.txt

while read LINE
do
    echo ====================== $LINE ==================== >> psnrdiff.txt
    echo Jpeg2000 >>  psnrdiff.txt
    compare -metric PSNR images/toconvert/$LINE images/converted/$LINE.jp2 images/psnrDiffs/$LINE.jp2.png >> psnrdiff.txt
done < lsout.txt
```

Comment: Your script is overly complicated and will break on some “weird” file names. Write `for x in images/toconvert/*; do … compare -metric PSNR "$x" "images/converted/${x##*/}.jp2" "images/converted/${x##*/}.jp2.png"; done`

Comment: i differ between three types .. i mentioned before it's just a "part" of my code and not even this part is in the current code form, but thanks

Comment: funny it's exactly the script I was trying to make too. same issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Various `imagemagick` command output to `STDERR` instead of `STDOUT`.

You can redirect `STDERR` to `STDOUT` to capture the output:

```
compare -metric PSNR .... >> psnrdiff.txt 2>&1
```

Comment: very weirdly in my case it creates a 144MB file if I do that. (every pixel in a PPM-like format is enumerated in there)

Answer (score 1):

```
ls images/toconvert/ > file.txt 
while read LINE
do
    echo ====================== $LINE ==================== >> psnrdiff.txt
    echo Jpeg2000 >>  psnrdiff.txt
    compare -metric PSNR "images/toconvert/$LINE" "images/converted/$LINE.jp2" "images/psnrDiffs/$LINE.jp2.png" >> psnrdiff.txt
done < file.txt
```

Comment: keeps printing it into console, but just the compare command return value is printed

Comment: Try the command suggested by Gnouc  in above piece of code.